# Can You Call '.after' Twice in a Function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am asking a question in good faith here. I've had a lot of trouble on StackOverflow; I *know* this is probably Googleable, but I lack the prerequisite knowledge to do so. Please keep that in mind and be kind.

**The Overall Goal**

I am creating a digital clock which functions normally for five minutes, and then accelerates rapidly for two minutes. Then, it will freeze for a certain amount of time, show the correct time, and the program repeats.

**Immediate Goal**

I need to call my `faketime` function from within my `time` function. When I add the second `.after`, I get an  `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`. As my indentation appears to fine, I think the issue is elsewhere. Can use you use `.after` twice in a function? If not, how can I accomplish this? Thank you!

**Code**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

# importing strftime function to
# retrieve system's time
from time import strftime

# creating tkinter window
root = Tk()
root.title('Clock')

# This function is used to
# display time on the label

def newtime():
    faketime = "Test"
    lbl.config(text=faketime)
    lbl.after(1000, time)


def time():
    string = strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    lbl.config(text=string)
    lbl.after(1000, time)
    lbl.after(300000, newtime())






# Styling the label widget so that clock
# will look more attractive
lbl = Label(root, font=('calibri', 40, 'bold'),
            background='black',
            foreground='red')

# Placing clock at the centre
# of the tkinter window
lbl.pack(anchor='center')
time()

mainloop()
```

Comment: Your indentation does 'look' fine.  I suspect you're mixing tabs and spaces in your indents?

Comment: This code does not appear to cause that error. The error is caused by wrong indentation, not the fact that `after` is being called twice. Side note though, this is wrong: `lbl.after(300000, newtime())`. You want `lbl.after(300000, newtime)`. You're currently calling the function then passing `None` to `after`, when you really want `after` to call the function later.

Comment: Thank you both - deleting and reindenting corrected that error. I still have some problems with the code, but I'll try and correct them on my own.

Answer (score -1):

- Line 18 should be `lbl.after(1000, newtime)` instead of `lbl.after(1000, time)`
- Comment out line 25 `#lbl.after(300000, newtime())`

**HAPPY NEW YEARS!**

Output image:

[image]